# Mageplaza_smtp module cannot be activated

Tags: smtp

everyone, I installed mageplaza_smtp module, tested the function, can send mail normally, but when I want to deactivate the problem encountered. As shown in the figure below, my configuration failed all the time, which made it impossible to save it. The log shows that curl returns a web page where I need to enter a graphical validation code to continue accessing the store. mageplaza. com address. But this is php's curl request. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? How should we solve it?

[image: active]

[image: response]

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 12:15:05 GMT

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Connection: close

CF-Chl-Bypass: 1

Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d1852120624c1f16ea5862f0b7af58fc71556194505; expires=Fri, 24-Apr-20 12:15:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.mageplaza.com; HttpOnly

Cache-Control: max-age=2

Expires: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 12:15:07 GMT

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Server: cloudflare

CF-RAY: 4cd03d8e281298d1-LAX

安全检查! | 百度云加速







body{margin:0;padding:0}

请打开cookies。
    
      
        只差一步
        输入验证码，可以浏览 store.mageplaza.com

```
  <div class="yjs-section yjs-highlight yjs-captcha-container">
    <div class="yjs-wrapper">
      <div class="yjs-columns two">
        <div class="yjs-column">
          <div class="yjs-highlight-inverse yjs-form-stacked">
            <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" method="get">
```

访问本页面,您的浏览器需要支持JavaScript

```
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="yjs-column">
          <div class="yjs-screenshot-container">

            <span class="yjs-no-screenshot"></span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.columns -->
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

  <div class="yjs-section yjs-wrapper">
    <div class="yjs-columns two">
      <div class="yjs-column">
        <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">为什么需要输入验证码?</h2>

        <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">输入验证码证明您不是机器人，输入后可以暂时浏览网站。</p>
      </div>

      <div class="yjs-column">
        <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">如何避免？</h2>

        <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">如果您使用私人电脑，可以下载杀毒软件，进行全盘扫描保证没有中毒。</p>

        <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">如果您使用公用电脑，可以请网络管理员修正配置选项或查找病毒来源。</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.section -->

  <div class="yjs-error-footer yjs-wrapper">
```

云加速 Event ID: **4cd03d8e281298d1**
    •
    你的IP: 61.140.180.132
    •
    帮助中心
    •
    百度云加速

```
</div><!-- /#yjs-error-details -->
```

window._yjs_translation = {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use magepal_smtp. It's better than mageplaze:
https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Comment: It works fine :)，thank you very much!